# Can I write "It is pity I didn't have a chance to know you better" on a mum's headstone?

Tags: expressions

When you lost someone when you were young, and it was your close family member, can you say "It is pity I didn't have a chance to know you better"? I mean write it on an inscription, headstone, etc.?
Thanks

Comment: You can say it is a pity, but usually the inscription speaks about the dead or from their words, not a quote from you.

Comment: I would suggest you discuss it with a friend or clergyman.

Comment: You can if you like but it wouldn't be correct English. However proofreadjng is off topic here.

Comment: This would not be the place to write your words. Their own words might be fitting. Just as well we don't do proofreedig

Comment: Well, who are the words on the headstone for, really?  Surely for yourself and for others who knew your mother, and might visit the grave in remembrance. That and maybe a few others who happen by, and whose thoughts you might wish to engage. However, there is usually not much room on a headstone, and the words are literally “carved in stone”.  If I were in your shoes, I would want to know what the other people thought.